# Does installing packages with a Python version, then downgrading it cause compatibility problems (e.g. module not found)?

Tags: python, conda, python-venv

TLDR: Does using a python version other than that which was used to initially install the packages in a conda env lead to compatibility problems?

In after creating a conda environment with python=3.11, and installing several packages from a requirements.txt file, all libraries except one were successfully installed. After trying different ways to install the last library, I figured that it might be a python version issue and so I executed 'conda install python=3.10' and retried. The last package was successfully installed but, after trying to run the python program I get an error saying that another library cannot be found. Is that due to the fact that packages were installed using a later version than the ones used to run the program?

Tried to check if it is a python interpreter issue in VS Code. It was not.

Comment: What package failed to install? The answer to this question will depend that, but in short: yes, downgrading can cause issues.

Comment: Each version of Python has its own separate module installation folder.  So if you install a module for, say, Python 3.9, that module will not be available for Python 3.8 or 3.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments highlight important aspects, but don't explain the mechanics. So, let's walk through it.

### Conda and Pip Installation Behavior

When you create a Conda environment with `python=3.11` it will install Python 3.11 and Pip. Within the environment, it creates a `lib/python3.11/site-packages` directory, which is where subsequent Python modules (the importable code chucks that Python packages deliver) will be installed.

If the `requirements.txt` file was a Pip requirements file, then the installation with implicitly run `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` and all packages will be installed to the `lib/python3.11/site-packages`.

Also, any Python packages you install with Conda will similarly get installed there, but Conda does the extra bookkeeping of tracking what you have defined as your environment (`python=3.11`, plus all Conda packages). It does not track the Pip-installed packages.

##### Conda-only just works

If you only had Conda-installed packages and then have Conda downgrade to `python=3.10`, it will also correctly uninstall all the `lib/python3.11/site-packages` and reinstall with matching `lib/python3.10/site-packages` versions.

##### Conda ignores Pip-installed packages

However, it's a different story for Pip-installed packages. Conda will not adjust these because they aren't included in Conda's bookkeeping. Hence, you may still have a bunch of packages residually left in the `lib/python3.11/site-packages` but they are no longer usable by the `python=3.10` that you have installed.

So, you must reinstall any Pip-installed packages.

### Better Strategy: YAML Environment Definition

A better strategy is to use a YAML file to manage everything. Something like:

**my_py310.yaml**

```
name: my_py310
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.10
  - pip

  ## Pip-installed packages
  - -r requirements.txt
```

then use

```
conda env create -n my_py310 -f my_py310.yaml
```

This way, if you had to downgrade, you can edit or create a new version of this file and then create a new environment from it with one command.

Any environment that mixes Conda and Pip packages is recommended to use this approach [as per the documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env).